# How to send didSelectRowAtIndexPath back to view controller in swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I have 1 viewController and 1 tableViewController in swift. I can send an NSMutableArray from the viewController to populate the tableViewController using segue. I do not know how to send the selected row back to the view controller. The code so far:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    // Missing code for sending back the selected row

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the delegation pattern. Create a protocol:

```
protocol MyDataDelegate {
    didSelectRow(row: NSIndexPath, data: MyData)
}
```

In the table controller, add a property:

```
var myDataDelegate: MyDataDelegate?
```

and in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` call the delegate method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    let data = getDataForRow(indexPath) // <== You need to implement it
    self.myDataDelegate?.didSelectRow(indexPath, data: data)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Next, in your main view controller:

- implement the `MyDataDelegate` protocol
- implement the MyDataDelegate.didSelectRow method
- right before presenting the table controller (or after creating it, if you manually do it), set the `myDataDelegate` property of the table controller to self

This way, when a row is selected in your table controller, the `didSelectRow` method is called on your main view controller, so you can do whatever you need with the index path and/or the data.

Of course feel free to change the `didSelectRow` signature (use the indexpath, or a row index, with or without data, etc.)

Comment: just add weak in front of ( var myDataDelegate: MyDataDelegate?) 
to avoid the risk of a "strong reference cycle"  :)